# Descenders in facet panel intrude on panel background

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot on a white background with grey facets and white facet text:

```
ggplot(data = data.frame(x = rep(1:2, 2), y = rep(1:2,2), color = c("Ap", "Ap", "B", "B")), 
       aes(x = x, y = y, color = color)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(~color) + 
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(), 
        strip.text = element_text(color = "white", size = 23))
```

[image]

My problem is that descenders (p, g, q, j) cross the facet. I would like the strip background to have a margin around the text so that all glyphs in the facet text are always strictly within the facet rectangle. I can add newlines to the facet text `color = c("Ap\n", "Ap\n", "B\n", "B\n")` but the margin is too excessive (or the `lineheight` required is too ugly). Is there a `ggplot2` solution to this?

Comment: I suppose you could fudge `vjust` to something like .8 in your `element_text`, though then you risk bumping into the top of the strip instead...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**For ggplot v2.2.0** In `theme`, specify margins in the `strip_text` element (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41428344/edit-strip-size-ggplot2/41428958#41428958))

```
# Set text size
size = 26

library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

p = ggplot(data = data.frame(x = rep(1:2, 2), y = rep(1:2,2), color = c("Ap", "Ap", "B", "B")), 
      aes(x = x, y = y, color = color)) + 
      geom_point() + 
      facet_grid(~color) + theme_bw() +
      theme(strip.text = element_text(color = "white", size = size)) 


  p +
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(margin = margin(.1, 0, .3, 0, "cm")))
```

**Original**
You could use the ggplot layout to adjust the height of the strip. The height could be set to an absolute height, for instance, `unit(1, "cm")`, or, as I've done here, set to a height that adjusts to the font size.

**Edit: Updating to ggplot2 2.0.0**
**Further edit: Updating to grid 3.0.0**   `grid:::unit.list()` no longer needed.

```
# Set text size
size = 26

library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

p = ggplot(data = data.frame(x = rep(1:2, 2), y = rep(1:2,2), color = c("Ap", "Ap", "B", "B")), 
      aes(x = x, y = y, color = color)) + 
      geom_point() + 
      facet_grid(~color) + theme_bw() +
      theme(strip.text = element_text(color = "white", size = size)) 


# Get ggplot grob
g <- ggplotGrob(p)

# Set the relevant height
g$heights[3] = unit(2, "grobheight", textGrob("a", gp=gpar(fontsize = size))) 


grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

[image]