# edit strip size ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have tried to apply this solution ([How can I change the size of the strip on facets in a ggplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27407355/how-can-i-change-the-size-of-the-strip-on-facets-in-a-ggplot])[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ys8eu.png))  to change the size of the strip on facets in a ggplot, I have increase the height size

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gtable)

d <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=gear)) + 
            geom_bar(aes(y=gear), stat="identity", position="dodge") +
            facet_wrap(~cyl)

g <- ggplotGrob(d)
g$heights[[3]] = unit(5,"in")

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

This is what I get, it does only increase the space (white) on the top of the strip:
[image]

Why does it work differently?

Comment: Newer versions of `ggplot2` have an overhauled facet system, which is why this no longer works.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

A simple solution is to specify the margins of your `strip.text` elements appropriately:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=gear)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y=gear), stat="identity", position="dodge") +
  facet_wrap(~cyl) + 
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(margin = margin(2,0,2,0, "cm")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Something like this seems to work:

```
g$heights[[6]] <- unit(5,"in")
g$grobs[[17]]$heights <- unit(2,"in")
g$grobs[[18]]$heights <- unit(2,"in")
g$grobs[[19]]$heights <- unit(2,"in")

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

Note that looking at `g$grobs` tells us grobs 17, 18 and 19 are the strips.

You can automate the second step with:

```
index <- which(sapply(g$grobs, function(x) x$name == "strip"))
g$grobs <- lapply(seq_along(g$grobs), function(.x) {
  if(.x %in% index) {
    g$grobs[[.x]]$heights <- unit(2,"in")
  } 
  g$grobs[[.x]]
} )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. So, basically `g$heights[[6]] <- unit(5,"in")` moves the strip, while `g$grobs[[17]]$heights <- unit(2,"in")` enlarges strip area. But I can not see the correlation between units

Comment: That's correct. It seems the units are a bit weird since `g$heights[[6]]` gives `5cm` after assigning inches. I just played around a bit.

Comment: there is no `[[<-` method for grid units. Only recently was one introduced for `[<-` but it note that it coerces the result to `unit.list`.