# How to decrease the height of the strips while hiding the text in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to change the size of the strips. I want them smaller than what i am getting as they are taking a lot of space. I tried the code in this thread: [edit strip size ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41428344/edit-strip-size-ggplot2/41428958#41428958).  The recommendation is to use `theme(strip.text.x = element_text(margin = margin(2,0,2,0, "cm")))`. It did not work because i cannot merge it with `theme(strip.text = element_blank())`. I include the latter line of code because i do not want the name of the countries to show in the strips, i add them manually using `geom_text`. Is there a way to keep the name of the countries hidden in the strips but make the size of the strips smaller in height?

[image]

Here is the code below (the code is long because i add manually a legend to the graph):

```
    library(gtable)
    library(gridExtra)
    library(ggplot2)
    

p1= df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x= estimate, y=term)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = cntry, x =  Inf, y = Inf), vjust = 1.75, hjust =1)+
  geom_point(mapping=aes(x=estimate, y=term)) +
  facet_wrap(vars(cntry,continent)) 


#Plot it
dummy= df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = estimate, y = term))+ 
  facet_wrap(vars(cntry,continent)) +
  geom_rect(aes(fill=continent), xmin=-Inf, xmax=Inf, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(strip.text = element_blank())


g1 <- ggplotGrob(p1)
g2 <- ggplotGrob(dummy)



gtable_select <- function (x, ...) 
{
  matches <- c(...)
  x$layout <- x$layout[matches, , drop = FALSE]
  x$grobs <- x$grobs[matches]
  x
}

panels <- grepl(pattern="panel", g2$layout$name)
strips <- grepl(pattern="strip-t", g2$layout$name)
g2$layout$t[panels] <- g2$layout$t[panels] - 1
g2$layout$b[panels] <- g2$layout$b[panels] - 1

new_strips <- gtable_select(g2, panels | strips)
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(new_strips)

gtable_stack <- function(g1, g2){
  g1$grobs <- c(g1$grobs, g2$grobs)
  g1$layout <- transform(g1$layout, z= z-max(z), name="g2")
  g1$layout <- rbind(g1$layout, g2$layout)
  g1
}

new_plot <- gtable_stack(g1, new_strips)
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(new_plot)

# Extract only the legend from "dummy" plot
g_legend <- function(dummy){ 
  tmp <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(dummy)) 
  leg <- which(sapply(tmp$grobs, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box") 
  legend <- tmp$grobs[[leg]] 
  return(legend)} 
# Assign the legend to a separate object
facet.legend <- g_legend(dummy)


jpeg("legend_graph.jpg", width = 8, height = 6, units = "in", res = 300)
print(grid.arrange(new_plot, facet.legend, nrow = 2, widths = c(7, 1), heights = c(6, 0.01)))
dev.off()
```

Here is the data:

```
structure(list(cntry = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("China", 
"USA", "Germany", "Canada"), class = "factor"), term = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L), .Label = c("2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", 
"2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017"), class = "factor"), estimate = c(-0.02, 
-0.02, -0.05, -0.01, 0, 0.02, -0.01, 0.03, 0.02, 0, 0.09, 0.1, 
0.04, 0.13, 0.1, 0.07, 0.08, 0.01, -0.1, -0.09, -0.1, -0.1, -0.13, 
-0.12, -0.18, -0.07, -0.04, 0.01, 0, -0.02, -0.02, 0.03, 0.01, 
0.01, 0.03, 0.03), continent = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Asia", 
"America", "Europe"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -36L
), class = "data.frame")
```